# Angular $watch on a recursive service function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I hate asking questions that there's already good info for but I'm missing something to keep my implementation from working.

My scenario is using a recursive function on a service to load my data in iterative chunks. All the data is captured by the scope but only the first set is displayed unless you navigate away and then back again. Clearly, I need to $watch my scope. I just can't figure out how to do so.

AccountService runs a method called getAccountsByPage which is passed an argument of 1. That function then calls itself with a value of 2, and so forth.

```
$routeProvider.when('/accounts/', {
    ...
    controller: function ($scope, AccountService) {
        var accounts = $scope.accounts = AccountService.getAccountsByPage(1);
        $scope.$watch('accounts', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log(newVal, oldVal);
        });
    }
});

console outputs: undefined, undefined
    [Object, Object, Object...] undefined
```

To be clear, getting the data isn't the problem. Updating the view is. Angular says not to use $watch on the controller but it seems that everyone does so...

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've posted, `$scope.accounts` only ever gets set once when the controller first gets instantiated. It doesn't matter what `AccountService.getAccountsByPage` is doing underneath. Whatever it returns will be put into `$scope.accounts`, and trigger the `$watch` that one time. It won't be triggered again until `$scope.accounts` changes, which I don't see happening anywhere from the code posted.